# How to read uploading files without sending it to a directory in php

Tags: php, file, file-upload

Am trying to read uploading files from a form inputs without sending it to a directory first. Is it posibble?

With code below I can read files **3.png** locally and its working.

```
$picture ='3.png';
$mydata = file_get_contents($picture);
// print files
echo $mydata;
```

**My issues:** when I post the same files from a form input and try to read it on the  fly. I cannot get it to work. Is it a must that I have to upload the files to a directory first before echoing its contents

```
$mydata_name =$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"];
$mydata =$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"];
// print files
echo $mydata;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$mydata = file_get_contents($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"])` when you do single file upload each time. Otherwise you need to use

```
foreach($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"] as $tmp_name){
    $mydatas[]= file_get_contents($tmp_name);
    // dosomething here.
}
```